# What is a persistent disk?

Tags: mongodb, ram, disk, hard-drive, solid-state-drive

I have been doing an online course in MongoDB, however I am frequently coming across a term called "Persistent disk". I have googled it out, but did not get a satisfying answer. Could you please help me out ?

Comment: A HDD, Solid State Hard Drive. Anything that retains its state AFTER computer shutdown. Surprised Google couldn't find a decent definition for that

Answer (score 2):

When your application runs (or Mongo in this case), it does all its work in RAM. RAM is not persistent because when you turn off your computer you permanently lose all the information stored in RAM.

Hard drives and SSDs on the otherhand *are* persistent. If you write something to them, it sticks for good.

So when you tell Mongo to insert a document, it *first* gets written into RAM, and then eventually gets written to the (persistent) disk. From an AppDev perspective is this all hidden from you and you (generally) just assume its written straight to desk

[This](https://youtu.be/oRDYNWCYnGo) is a good video from what I guess to be the Mongo course you're taking that talks about the transition from memory to disk.

Comment: Great answer David..Thanks !! However, I have another doubt here, that if   the data is large, then how the RAM is going to hold it ? If the RAM is less than the data to be inserted, then what happens that time ? Any data loss occurs ?

Comment: @Sourav This is getting outside the scope of the question. You need to google on how RAM works. The very short version is that there is something called paging which lets RAM only load part of the data at a time, while the rest of it is stored on disk.

Comment: @Sourav Also, if you think my answer was great please upvote/accept it :).